# RegExp: Key Value pairs with value lists enclosed by { and } or quotes

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that will capture the following:

1. key
2. key=value
3. key="some \"value\" escaped"
4. key={value1,value2}

The key/value pair will be joined by a string, so:

```
key,key1=value1,key2={foo,bar},key3="some description for \"foo\"",...
```

Currently, I have the following:

```
(\w+)|((?:\\.|[^=,]+)*)=("(?:\\.|[^"\\]+)*"|(?:\\.|[^,"\\\{\}]+)*)
```

It captures (1), (2) and (3) but not (4).

The regular expression will be parsed with Java.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this longish regex:

```
(\b\w+)(?:=((?:\{[^}]+\}|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\w+)))?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW9aC8/1)